# How to create a new text file at the cmd prompt with the end result allowing me to rename the file?

Tags: cmd.exe

I would like an exact duplicate of the following procedure on a Windows computer using mouse clicks: Right Click in a directory and choose New and then Text Document.

When one does this, the text file is created with a default name of New Text Document AND it is also highlighted so that I can type in my own file name.

I would like to do this in cmd. I don't care what file name is originally created. What I want is for the name of the file to automatically be highlighted / able to be renamed, so that I can rename it.

How can cmd execute / simulate a rename command / an F2 being pressed on the keyboard to a file that it has just created?

Comment: What does your own research suggest?

Comment: What I want done is either not possible, which I find interesting, because I thought every single mouse action on a Windows computer could be duplicated via DOS, or much people are not interested in what I am interested in for the sake of saving a few seconds and  having to do as little steps as possible.

Comment: If I may ask, why do you want to do this? I mean, what are you trying to achieve (or why are you trying to achieve it this way... there could be better/other solutions if we know why)

Comment: I don't like having to Right Click, Choose New, and then New Text Document. My computer is slow and the right click window and sub-menus take too long to appear. Also, I love keyboard shortcuts (for speed sake and ease of use) and being able to do things in as few steps as possible.

Comment: `C:\blah>copy con a.txt`     `C:\blah>ren a.txt a2.txt`  maybe go to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access and try to explain yourself, because you are communicating very poorly

Comment: the cmd prompt doesn't duplicate mouse actions.. autohotkeys or autoit might be able to, but it does have commands for renaming files. it wouldn't easily know you just created one.. though it could..

Comment: cmd could potentially find the file created in the last 2 minutes and rename that. maybe a batch guru can help there. Out of interest, what is the toolbar you say you use?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Now. I finished it :D

So we have to create a new file and name it what we want, right?

so since i do not know how to use pop-up windows, i'll be using cmd to enter the name of the file :D it also makes the .bat shorter :)

Here we go.

Create a new text document. Open it. Type this in:

@echo off

set /p name=Enter File Name:

start notepad %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%name%.txt

Now click on the upper right File -> Save As.. -> and save it as file.bat

Now double click it (or click it then hit enter) and tadaa! :D

Now to explain.

Line #1 - @Echo off, no average user wants to see the script and what it says and does! So, lets hide it.

Line #2 - set /p name=Enter File Name: , this does two things. Its easier to explain the last part then the first. It will ask for the user to input something, and will then use the set command to give "name" what the user inputed.

Line #3 - start notepad %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%name%.txt , this creates a file using notepad in the current user's desktop, and uses the user input for "name" as the new text document's name :p

This could be built upon, to ask the user to also ask what the suffix (i.e. .bat, .vbs, .txt, etc) could be, or to sort it into different folders, etc etc :D the possibilities are endless!

Hope this finally helped haha sorry about that :p

Comment: nope, he said he'd like the file to be created, not opened.

Comment: I think perhaps he wants to rename a file in a directory, where the file was created like in the last 2min, i suppose that's possible somehow.

Comment: @Outride Thank you. Since exactly what I wanted seems to not be possible, the solution that you offered is what I was working on, except I am using copy NUL %filename%.txt which doesn't give me the Windows prompt asking me if I want to create the file because it can't find it. I was however trying to execute all of this in one line, which I am having trouble with. I will post this issue in another question. As for the location where the text file is saved, I wanted it to be saved in whatever folder I have open. I don't know how that would work other than maybe copying the bat file to where I

Comment: want to add the text file. However, since the toolbar program of StExBar opens the command prompt with the location of the folder I am currently in already specified, this isn't going to be a problem.

Comment: @barlop I wanted the file to be created, not opened, and a chance for me to rename it. However, being able to specify the name of the file on the spot via user input and then it opening, was another solution that I am comfortable with. Having the file created with a name I didn't want and then me renaming it after typing into the opened notepad file and saving it was something I did not want for fear of forgetting to rename the saved file. It might seem silly to some, but the logical order is important to me.

Comment: @Rolo You write "However, being able to specify the name of the file on the spot via user input and then it opening, was another solution that I am comfortable with" <-- But writing `C:\blah>notepad abc.txt<ENTER>`  where abc.txt does not exist, will do that. It will prompt for creation of the file. When outride answered with that, you said you weren't interested. You are very bad at communicating what you want. Open a cmd prompt to automatically go to folder `c:\blah`

Comment: @barlop C:\blah>notepad abc.txt<ENTER> asks if I want to create abc.txt. It does NOT ask what filename I want to give my about to be created text file. They are very different outcomes. You are the one who is very bad at understanding outcomes as well as what I have asked and said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14869/discussion-between-barlop-and-rolo).

Answer (score 0):

To create a file that you can name, simply type in the following code into command prompt:

**start notepad file.txt**


 Then press enter

Just change the preffix "file" to what you wish to name the file. Make sure to keep the .txt part!


NOTE* Once you do that, the file will be created, but its location of the text file will be C:\Users\YOURUSER hope this helps!

EDIT* I'm sorry i was straightforward. You can always type in  /? and cmd will print out a quick description, and what the command can do and what can follow it. 

So, typing in start /? , you'll see a list of codes that may follow the "start" command. "/?" is always your friend. If in doubt,  /? that's how I was taught :p

Comment: Thanks, but I am not interested in this, as I would like the file to be created in whatever folder I already have opened up. I have a toolbar that opens up command prompt with the current folder already specified, but even then, I would then have to go to the file and rename it after creating it. I would like to do it before the way one can with right click > new > Text Doccument.

Comment: @Rolo So use the "start notepad <pathforfile>\MyFileName.txt" or whatever you wish the file to be named :) just specify the path file :D

Comment: Like I said, I have a toolbar program that already puts in the file path of the current folder I am in when I open DOS via the toolbar program. The part I don't like is having to rename the file after I have closed it. I would like the file to be created, not opened, and for me to rename it by simply typing a new name and not having to right click and choose rename or press F2. I would like the procedure to be done the exact way it is done by Right clicking, then selecting New, and then New Text Document.

Comment: Well with DOS you don't get the "pretty" GUI, it's a text based, raw-to-the-point. You won't be able to "highlight" it, but you'll be able to write in the name of the text file with "start notepad MyFileName.txt" or if you already created it, you could rename the file using DOS type in "rename <filepath>\MyFileName.txt MyFileName2.txt" :)

Comment: I don't want anything highlighted in DOS. There is some instruction in the background that Windows carries out when one creates a new text file via Right Click, New > Text Document. It is the renaming command. This instruction is carried out after the file is created. I figured there should be / might be a way to tell DOS to do this. To simulate a F2 press / a rename command on a file after it has created it and closed the DOS window.

Comment: Ugh sorry guys i'll go back and edit that, i assumed he knew it would be DOS as he was speaking of DOS, and even tagged it so :) *edited the answer, the command should be typed into Command Prompt* :) thanks for the point-out @DaveRook

Comment: This is being typed into a program that allows me to type commands that it will then execute. It's similar to creating and running a bat file.

Comment: Okay, I do not know if your question was answered or not.. So you've lost me. You can simply type in "start notepad <pathforfile>\MyFileName.txt" to create a new file, or type in "rename <filepath>\MyFileName.txt MyFileName2.txt" to change the name of a file, into command prompt or into a .bat file and then execute (double click) it :)

Comment: No, the question has not been answered. I will be creating notepad files on the spot / randomly -- the same way a user would when Right Clicking & then Choosing New > Text Document. I want this EXACT procedure to be duplicated without me having to use the mouse. So, when the instructions are executed, the following happens: 1) a text file is created (and not opened), 2) for this just created text file, I am allowed to rename it because an automatic simulated F2 (rename) was pressed on the keyboard. I don't know how else to explain this any clearer as it's more than clear. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate the prompt of: Cannot find the file.txt file. Do you want to create a new file?

Comment: Ohhh okay I see. Sorry for that. Okay, so to address each,
Step 1 - Create
The start command works here.
start notepad <pathforfile>\MyFileName.txt
Step 2 - Rename Ability
Would a popup query that requests the user to input what they want the file to be named? so lets say i type in "cookies" into the pop up, so it renames the file "cookies.txt"

then you could create a .bat file that executes step one (start, which generates the file) then step two (rename, asks for user input, uses that as the name of file) how about that? :D i do not know the code for a pop up window though :( sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This prompts you for a file name, then creates the file with the name you've given it, appending '.txt' to the end, to indicate to the OS that it should be interpreted as a text file.

```
@echo off
set /p file="Enter desired file name: "
type NUL > %file%.txt
```

Put that in a file whose name ends in `.bat` and you're in business.

edit: Oh, wait... You actually want a GUI prompt for the filename? Whoops... I'll get back to you. In the meanwhile, I'd recommend looking into Tcl/Tk or AutoHotKey, both of which are better scripting languages than batch files.

Comment: Incidentally, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file) gives an enormous number of different ways to get the functionality you want.